# Show that $F$ is normal family

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $D$ be the open unit disk and $H(D)$ be the set containing all holomorphisms $h:D\rightarrow D$. If $F\subset H(D)$ and there exists $g\in H(D)$ such that for all $f\in F$ and $k\geq 0$, $|f^{(k)}(0)|\leq|g^{(k)}(0)|$, show that $F$ is a normal family.

I still have no idea now. Any ideas or theorems which could be used here?

Comment: Montel's theorem should be useful (Probably, you don't know any other theorem which allows you to prove that a set is normal...)

Answer (score 2):

This is a strange problem. The family of all holomorphic functions bounded by $1$ is already normal. Hence its subfamily $F$ is normal too.

Maybe the real purpose of the problem is to show that $F$ is actually compact, not merely normal.  That is, in addition to saying that every subsequence has a locally uniformly convergent subsequence, you can also prove that the limit is in $F$. This follows from Cauchy's integral formula for derivatives.